# Was gret ever a valid past tense of greet?

Tags: history

The past tense of greet is greeted. This is known.

However my instinct suggests it should be something like great/gret (first spelling seeming more right though easy to confuse ).

I'm certain I can remember hearing people in the north of Britain saying gret.

Is there any validity at all to this word as a dialectical or previously acceptable form?

Or am I merely guilty of some phenomena where I misapply rules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Bosworth-Toller](http://bosworth.ff.cuni.cz/017502) indicates that the long vowel in Old English *grétan* was retained in the past tense and participle, with gemination (doubling) of the /t/.

The U.Michigan [Middle English Dictionary](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=70433666&egdisplay=compact&egs=70449167) cites (with modern diacritics to indicate conjectured pronunciations) the spellings *grette, grætte, gratte & grẹ̄t, grē̆t, greite & (late & rare) grẹ̄ted*, which suggest that from the 12th to the 15th century pronunciation varied between long and short, with the short appearing to be more common. The modern regularized form *greeted* seems to have arisen in the last part of the 15th century—that is, after the Great Vowel Shift had started.

I would not be surprised, then, to find pasts like *gret* or *grat* lingering in some dialects; but I find no direct evidence of that. [The English Dialect Dictionary](https://archive.org/stream/cu31924088038397#page/n733/mode/2up) does give orthographic *graet, grat, greeted, greht, gret, gruot*; but these are all associated with the unrelated northern (Yorkshire to the Islands) verb *greet* in the sense “weep”.

Comment: Who'd a thunk? What fun!

Comment: I've certainly heard such uses as, for example 'the puir lass gret her eyes out', but i don't think i've heard anything like 'the minister gret people at the door'.

Comment: My family are mostly from the north of the UK and I've never heard greet meaning weep. Interesting. How did greeted come to be the standard past tense word? It just seems so...clunky.

Comment: @greeted I imagine pretty much the same way as all the other choices: we held an election and *greeted* won.